# Why RaisedButton and TextField do not inherit the dimensions of the parent Container widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Why RaisedButton and TextField do not inherit the dimensions of the parent Container widget.
I want to be able to accurately determine the size of buttons and inputs.

[Draw raisedButton and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Iuh.png)

The Row in which my two widgets input and button are initialized

```
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              input(Icon(Icons.lock), 'Токен бота', _botTokenController, false,
                  widthPercent: 80,
                  height: 35,
                  context: context,
                  paddingLeft: 50,
                  paddingRight: 0),
              button('Добавить', () => {print('hello world')},
                  paddingLeft: 0,
                  widthPercent: 10,
                  context: context,
                  height: 35,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 51, 103, 1),
                  fontSize: 14),
            ],
          ),
```

input widget (TextField)

```
Widget input(
  Icon icon,
  String hint,
  TextEditingController controller,
  bool obscure, {
  double height = 50,
  double width = 460,
  double paddingLeft = 20,
  double paddingRight = 20,
  BuildContext context,
  double borderRadius = 0,
  double widthPercent = 0,
  double fontSize = 16,
}) {
  if (context != null) {
    if (widthPercent > 0 && widthPercent <= 100) {
      width = widthPercent / 100 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    } else {
      width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    }
  }

  return Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: paddingLeft, right: paddingRight),
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: TextField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: obscure,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, color: textPrimaryColor),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          isDense: true, // Added this
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: fontSize,
              color: Colors.black54),
          hintText: hint,
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87, width: 2)),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 1)),
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black54),
              child: icon,
            ),
          )),
    ),
  );
}
```

button widget (RaisedButton)

```
Widget button(String label, void func(),
    {BuildContext context = null,
    double borderRadius = 0,
    double paddingLeft = 20,
    double paddingRight: 20,
    double width = 460,
    double widthPercent = 0,
    double height = 50,
    double fontSize = 16,
    Color bacground = buttonPrimaryColor,
    FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeight.bold,
    Color fontColor = textPrimaryColor}) {
  if (context != null) {
    if (widthPercent > 0 && widthPercent <= 100) {
      width = widthPercent / 100 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    }
  }

  return Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: paddingLeft, right: paddingRight),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        func();
      },
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: paddingLeft, right: paddingRight),
      highlightColor: bacground,
      color: bacground,
      child: Text(label,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: fontWeight, color: fontColor, fontSize: fontSize)),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius)),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: user Flexible() widget as a parent of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) it resizes widgets based on the parents dimensions,

```
FractionallySizedBox(
           heightFactor: 0.7,//70% height of your parent widget
           widthFactor: 0.6,//60% width of your parent widget
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra padding or bring the padding our side the container. Remove the below code.

Button:

```
  Widget button(
  String label,
  void func(), {
  BuildContext context = null,
  double borderRadius = 0,
  double paddingLeft = 20,
  double paddingRight: 20,
  double width = 460,
  double widthPercent = 0,
  double height = 50,
  double fontSize = 16,
  FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeight.bold,
}) {
  if (context != null) {
    if (widthPercent > 0 && widthPercent <= 100) {
      width = widthPercent / 100 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    }
  }

  return Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        func();
      },
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: paddingLeft, right: paddingRight),
      highlightColor: Colors.red,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text(label,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: fontWeight, color: Colors.red, fontSize: fontSize)),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius)),
    ),
  );
}
```

Input:

```
Widget input(
  Icon icon,
  String hint,
  TextEditingController controller,
  bool obscure, {
  double height = 50,
  double width = 460,
  double paddingLeft = 20,
  double paddingRight = 20,
  BuildContext context,
  double borderRadius = 0,
  double widthPercent = 0,
  double fontSize = 16,
}) {
  if (context != null) {
    if (widthPercent > 0 && widthPercent <= 100) {
      width = widthPercent / 100 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    } else {
      width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    }
  }

  return Container(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: TextField(
      controller: controller,
      obscureText: obscure,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          isDense: true, // Added this
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: fontSize,
              color: Colors.black54),
          hintText: hint,
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87, width: 2)),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 1)),
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: IconTheme(
              data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black54),
              child: icon,
            ),
          )),
    ),
  );
}
```